# How to SharePoint Migration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, migration

Has anyone migrate from SP2010 to 2016 on premises? I Need help to walk me through some steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's quite a question!

There are many things to consider during a SharePoint migration, and many factors involve your specific environment.

Generally speaking, you have two options for migration.

1. Content Database attach method - double hop
2. 3rd party migration tool, e.g. ShareGate/Metalogix

For option 1, you will need to setup an intermediary 2013 farm. Once this farm is setup, you can migrate backup and restore your content databases, and attach to the web application on your 2013 farm to begin the upgrade process. Once all your content databases are upgraded, you will need to repeat this process with a 2016 destination farm.

For option 2, you will need to purchase a 3rd party migration tool that meets your needs. I've had good luck with ShareGate, however many of my colleagues prefer Metalogix. Once you've procured the software, you will need to setup your 2016 destination farm, and use the tool to migrate content.

Please feel free to contact me if you have any more specific questions, and keep in mind - a migration can be as large and complex as your SharePoint environment.

Hope this helps!